# Typescript React prop types with two possibilities

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to learn and implement Typescript in my new React project. I have a component `ToggleButton` that I want to use on two occasions, `sorting` and `filtering` products. Each toggle option has it's own button, but depending on if it is a `sorting` or `filtering` option there is a slight difference

```
type OrderBy = {
  value: ProductOrderBy
  children: ReactNode
  onClick: (arg0: ProductOrderBy) => void
}

type SizeFilter = {
  value?: ProductSize
  children: ReactNode
  onClick: (arg0?: ProductSize) => void
}

const ToggleButton = ({ value, children, onClick }: OrderBy | SizeFilter) => {
  const handleClick = () => onClick(value)
  return <Button onClick={handleClick}>{children}</Button>
}
```

As you can see, in case it's a `filter` option, the `value` is optional. Because the `value` is used as a parameter in the callback, also the callback parameter is optional.

I expected that the union `|` would state that the props have to match either the `OrderBy` or `SizeFilter` type. But in the intellisense of my IDE it looks like both types are merged.

My code works as expected, but my IDE tells me on the `onClick(value)` the following: `Argument of type 'ProductOrderBy | ProductSize | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.`

I can think of many workarounds to get around this problem, but as I'm still trying to learn Typescript I like to know why my typing isn't working as expected...?

Answer (score 0):

```
const ToggleButton = ({ value, children, onClick }: OrderBy | SizeFilter) => {
  if(!value) {
    return null;
  }
  const handleClick = () => onClick(value)
  return <Button onClick={handleClick}>{children}</Button>
}
```

This is because of SizeFilter where value can be undefined.

Comment: In case of size filter value is optional